# Reading data from mutiple sheets of same workbook Selenium

Tags: java, excel, selenium

Pls help me with the code to read data from multiple sheets of the same excel file using Selenium and Java code.Please find below the code which I have tried.It is reading the data from last sheet always.but I need to read data from sheet 0 to sheet n.

```
    public class HybridExecuteTest {
    WebDriver webdriver = null;
    @Test(dataProvider="hybridData")
    public void testLogin(String testcaseName,String keyword,String    objectName,String objectType,String value) 
        throws Exception {
            if(testcaseName!=null&&testcaseName.length()!=0){
    webdriver=new FirefoxDriver();
    webdriver.manage().window().maximize();
            }
    ReadObject object = new ReadObject();
    Properties allObjects =  object.getObjectRepository();
    UIOperation operation = new UIOperation(webdriver);
    //Call perform function to perform operation on UI
    operation.perform(allObjects,keyword,objectName,objectType,value);
            }
    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    @DataProvider(name="hybridData")
    public Object[][] get() throws IOException
    {
    Object[][] object = null; 
    String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\";
    System.out.println("File Path is:" + filePath);
    String fileName = "TestCaseRep.xls";
    //Create a object of File class to open xlsx file
    File file = new File(filePath+"\\"+fileName);
    //Create an object of FileInputStream class to read excel file
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    int totalSheet = 0;
    Sheet  Sheet1=null;
    Workbook Workbookone = null;
    //Find the file extension by spliting file name in substing and getting only extension name
    String fileExtensionName = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf("."));
    //Check condition if the file is xlsx file
    if(fileExtensionName.equals(".xlsx")){
    //If it is xlsx file then create object of XSSFWorkbook class
        Workbookone  = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    }
    //Check condition if the file is xls file
    else if(fileExtensionName.equals(".xls")){
        //If it is xls file then create object of XSSFWorkbook class
        Workbookone  = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    }
    //Read sheet inside the workbook by its name
    totalSheet = Workbookone.getNumberOfSheets();
    if(totalSheet > 0) {
        System.out.println("Total Sheet Found:" + totalSheet);
        for(int k=0;k<totalSheet ;k++) {
            System.out.println("Sheet Name:" + Workbookone.getSheetName(k));
            Sheet1 = Workbookone.getSheetAt(k);
            System.out.println("Sheet Found:" + Sheet1);
         //Find number of rows in excel file
    int rowCount = Sheet1.getLastRowNum()-Sheet1.getFirstRowNum();
    object = new Object[rowCount][5];
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        //Loop over all the rows
        Row row = Sheet1.getRow(i+1);
        //Create a loop to print cell values in a row
        for (int j = 0; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
            //Print excel data in console
            object[i][j] = row.getCell(j).toString();   
            System.out.println(object[i][j]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
 }
    return object;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show your code that you have tried, to get any help with it.

Comment: I have given the code above.Pls help me ..

Comment: Are you sure that `System.out.println("Sheet Name:" + Workbookone.getSheetName(k));` is printing the correct values

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are reinitializing the `object` varaible in the for loop that's why you are getting the values of last sheet.
As it is an two dimensional array You can store only two values row and columns.

If you want to store sheet as well you have to go for three dimensional array.But I suggest you to go for List. So I have modified the return type from `Object[][]` to `ArrayList<Object[][]>` so that sheet datas are added to List

```
public ArrayList<Object[][]> get() throws IOException {
        ArrayList<Object[][]> sheetDatas=new ArrayList<>();
        Object[][] object = null;
        String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\";
        System.out.println("File Path is:" + filePath);
        String fileName = "TestCaseRep.xls";
        //Create a object of File class to open xlsx file
        File file = new File(filePath + "\\" + fileName);
        //Create an object of FileInputStream class to read excel file
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        int totalSheet = 0;
        Sheet Sheet1 = null;
        Workbook Workbookone = null;
        //Find the file extension by spliting file name in substing and getting only extension name
        String fileExtensionName = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf("."));
        //Check condition if the file is xlsx file
        if (fileExtensionName.equals(".xlsx")) {
            //If it is xlsx file then create object of XSSFWorkbook class
            Workbookone = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        } //Check condition if the file is xls file
        else if (fileExtensionName.equals(".xls")) {
            //If it is xls file then create object of XSSFWorkbook class
            Workbookone = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        }
        //Read sheet inside the workbook by its name
        totalSheet = Workbookone.getNumberOfSheets();
        if (totalSheet > 0) {
            System.out.println("Total Sheet Found:" + totalSheet);
            for (int k = 0; k < totalSheet; k++) {
                System.out.println("Sheet Name:" + Workbookone.getSheetName(k));
                Sheet1 = Workbookone.getSheetAt(k);
                System.out.println("Sheet Found:" + Sheet1);
                //Find number of rows in excel file
                int rowCount = Sheet1.getLastRowNum() - Sheet1.getFirstRowNum();
                /**
                 * 
                 * You are reinitializing the object here so old datas will be lost
                 */
                object = new Object[rowCount][5];
                for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
                    //Loop over all the rows
                    Row row = Sheet1.getRow(i + 1);
                    //Create a loop to print cell values in a row
                    for (int j = 0; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
                        //Print excel data in console
                        object[i][j] = row.getCell(j).toString();
                        System.out.println(object[i][j]);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("");
                sheetDatas.add(object);
            }
        }
        return sheetDatas;
    }
}
```

For example If you want to get value from sheet 2
you can call like list.get(1)